# Add custom image in Android AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I compiled kernel source and generated the Image. Now, in order to flash it on an android Emulator, I created an AVD and in the process, I was not able to choose the image which I generated.

Any ideas how to do it?

Currently I'm trying it in Android Studio. Is there any workaround to boot the emulator with custom image without Android Studio?

Comment: any success on this?

Comment: No progress on this still.